# How to update custom rendered maps?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've created a CustomMap in my shared project extending from `Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map`.

I've also created the custom renderers for iOS and Android. The problem is: I'm trying to update the user's location related to the destination so I need to update that map with the new polylines from Google. But I don't know how.

I thought about creating a method in my CustomMap class to be overridden in my renderer, but the renderer only uses my CustomMap class as a ExportRenderer type, the class itself derives from MapRenderer.

How can I control this update from my CustomMap class? That way from my Shared Project code I could do `CustomMap.Update(new Polylines)`

Project Structure:

- Solution

  - Shared project

    - CustomMap : Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map
  - iOS project

    - CustomMapRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Maps.iOS.MapRenderer
  - Android project

    - CustomMapRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CustomMap.cs:

```net
public static BindableProperty TestProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "Test",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(CustomMap),
    defaultValue: "test",
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
    propertyChanged: HandleTestChanged);

public string Test
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
}

private static void HandleTestChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var customMap = (CustomMap)bindable;
    // do something with new value
}
```

Then in your renderer:

```net
var customMap = (CustomMap)Element;
var test = customMap.Test;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I needed to call a method, like Update and then that call would trigger in my renderer a redrawing of the route. Can I use the same approach with Bindable properties? Thanks!

Comment: You could use Bindable properties for that OR just create a method which uses event handlers for that (subscribe to them in renderer constructor).

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to make it work with not much success. I created the property in my CustomMap class, but how do I check in my renderer if the property has changed? Thanks.